# YOLO Nas model: print evaluation metrics when testing

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, yolonas

I'm trying to train a YOLO Nas model. For training, after each epoch it was showing the latest metrics, MAP and F1 numbers. But when I want to test it on the test data, it doesn't print anything to know how model is performing. What should I add here so it can print all those metrics?

```
best_model = models.get(
    MODEL_ARCH,
    num_classes=len(dataset_params['classes']),
    checkpoint_path=f"{CHECKPOINT_DIR}/{EXPERIMENT_NAME}/RUN_20231019_025212_979921/average_model.pth"
).to(DEVICE)

#evaluate model

trainer.test(
    model=best_model,
    test_loader=test_data,
    test_metrics_list=DetectionMetrics_050(
        score_thres=0.1,
        top_k_predictions=300,
        num_cls=len(dataset_params['classes']),
        normalize_targets=True,
        post_prediction_callback=PPYoloEPostPredictionCallback(
            score_threshold=0.01,
            nms_top_k=1000,
            max_predictions=300,
            nms_threshold=0.7
        )
    )
)
```